# Не работает адаптер Bluetooth в Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

Не работает адаптер Bluetooth в Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Я новичек). Я уже просто не в силах самостоятельно искать ответ и хочу выкинуть ноут с окна. Пожалуйста помогите!!!

```
hciconfig up
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
DOWN 
RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
TX bytes:9 acl:0 sco:0 commands:3 errors:0

sudo hciconfig hci0 up
[sudo] пароль для user: 
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)

sudo rfkill list 
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
6: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

sudo hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device
```

вывод lsmod:

```
ccm                    20480  9
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
btusb                  61440  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
btintel                32768  1 btusb
intel_rapl_common      24576  1 intel_rapl_msr
uvcvideo              106496  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
bluetooth             651264  5 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,btusb
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   147456  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       61440  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
snd_hda_intel          53248  6
videodev              249856  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
kvm_amd               118784  0
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
mc                     57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hda_codec         147456  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           94208  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm                   864256  1 kvm_amd
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
amdgpu               6348800  31
snd_pcm               114688  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
joydev                 28672  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
mt7921e                77824  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
mt76_connac_lib        36864  1 mt7921e
iommu_v2               24576  1 amdgpu
aesni_intel           376832  6
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
gpu_sched              36864  1 amdgpu
mt76                   77824  2 mt7921e,mt76_connac_lib
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 amdgpu
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
rapl                   20480  0
mac80211             1028096  3 mt76,mt7921e,mt76_connac_lib
ttm                    69632  2 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper
drm_kms_helper        253952  1 amdgpu
wmi_bmof               16384  0
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
cec                    53248  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
hid_multitouch         28672  0
serio_raw              20480  0
rc_core                61440  1 cec
efi_pstore             16384  0
snd                    94208  22 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
k10temp                16384  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0
cfg80211              888832  4 mt76,mt7921e,mac80211,mt76_connac_lib
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
snd_pci_acp3x          20480  0
ccp                    98304  1 kvm_amd
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       114688  1 ipmi_devintf
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   557056  18 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,ttm
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_generic            16384  0
mfd_aaeon              16384  0
asus_wmi               36864  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon
xhci_pci               24576  0
ahci                   40960  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
i2c_piix4              28672  0
libahci                36864  1 ahci
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
nvme                   49152  2
i2c_hid_acpi           16384  0
r8169                  77824  0
i2c_hid                28672  1 i2c_hid_acpi
realtek                32768  1
nvme_core             126976  3 nvme
wmi                    32768  3 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon
video                  53248  1 asus_wmi
hid                   139264  3 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
```

Comment: у меня такой же есть) перевоткнешь пару раз - заработает. лучше поменяй его

Comment: а там ноут... в леново помогало убивание леновского драйвера с переходом на стандартный. может с асусом тоже прокатит. не помню как... покажи lsmod

Comment: @eri поменять кого?

Comment: @eri Выполнено, мой милорд!

Comment: три кавычки ``` текст ```

Comment: @eri Сделал....

Comment: Попробуй заблеклистить asus_wmi и перезагрузиться. Шанс не велик, но может поможет

Comment: @eri Не подскажите как это сделать?